# Discord bot not recognizing commands

Tags: python, bots, discord

I'm new to the discord API and I'm having trouble figuring out why my commands are not recognized. I've read through the documentation, but I'm not exactly sure where to look. Any help would be appreciated. Don't mind the hard-coded lists. I plan on changing that in the future. For now I just want to make sure that it works.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot online!")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def add_roles(member, *roles):
    if message.content.startswith("!role"):
        role_list = ["CS101", "CS492", "CS360", "CS213", "CS228", "CS401", "CS440", "CS450", "CS480", "CS410", "CS420", "CS430", "CS108", "CS111", "CS226", "CS312", "CS405", "CS413", "CS435", "CS499", "CS250", "CS475", "CS445"]
        entered_role = message.content[6:].upper()
        role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=entered_role)

        if role is None or role.name not in role_list:
            # If the role wasn't found by discord.utils.get() or is a role that we don't want to add:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "Role doesn't exist.")
            return
        elif role in message.author.roles:
            # If they already have the role
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "You already have this role.")
        else:
            try:
                await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
                await client.send_message(message.channel, "Successfully added role {0}".format(role.name))
            except discord.Forbidden:
                await client.send_message(message.channel, "I don't have perms to add roles.")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def remove_roles(member, *roles):
    if message.content.startswith("!unassign"):
        role_list = ["CS101", "CS492", "CS360", "CS213", "CS228", "CS401", "CS440", "CS450", "CS480", "CS410", "CS420", "CS430", "CS108", "CS111", "CS226", "CS312", "CS405", "CS413", "CS435", "CS499", "CS250", "CS475", "CS445"]
        roles_cleared = True

        for r in role_list:
            # Check every role
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=r)
            if role in message.author.roles:
                # If they have the role, get rid of it
                try:
                    await client.remove_roles(message.author, role)
                except discord.Forbbiden:
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "I don't have perms to remove roles.")
                    roles_cleared = False
                    break

        if roles_cleared:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "Roles successfully cleared.")

client.run("mytoken")
```

Comment: Your function name is the command name

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

In function you need to have ctx variable

```
@client.comman(pass_context = True)
async def some_command(ctx, bla_bla, and_bla_bla):
      pass
```

i think...
tell if it was helpful for u